# Trigger Inkwell without tapping on it

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to trigger an `Inkwell` widget without actually tapping it. I'm not sure how to tackle this problem because it is not mentioned anywhere in the docs.
So the goal is to activate the `onTap` and display the ripple effect created by the `Inkwell`
Any ideas?

Comment: Hrm, this seems like it me be very challenging as a lot of the TapDownDetails and GestureDetection is accessible via public APIs. Perhaps you can find a way to simulate the platform tap that then bubbles up to the InkWell or maybe you can try replicating the InkWell/InkResponse/TapDownDetail, etc as to expose the method to simulate a tap down and the associated pointer information.

Comment: You could get that `InkWell` using a GlobalKey. Get it's state. And directly call the corresponding method by looking at the source code (even if private).

Comment: @Darky But using global keys is slow and discouraged no?

Comment: Usually yeah. But that is one of the rare use cases where it's used : To call methods of other non-inherited widgets.

Comment: Hello! Have you ever found a way to do this? Could someone show a possible example of those suggestions by @RémiRousselet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get here years later like me:

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783634/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-touch-on-a-specific-position-of-a-widget-or-screen) it is possible to trigger a click in a widget. With that possibility you're able to find the Inkwell (using GlobalKey) and trigger a click in it's offset, kind like it was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291245/get-y-position-of-container-on-flutter).

Something like this:

```
RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

WidgetsBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(
  pointer: 0,
  position: position,
));
WidgetsBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(
  pointer: 0,
  position: position,
));
```