# Get position and size of Widget during build

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get the size and position of a widget during the `build()` method? In the following code, I want to draw rectangle in the `CustomPaint` widget that is centered and is a certain percentage of the remaining area of the viewport, which is everything below below the `Text` widget, marked `(A)`. I can get the width from `MediaQuery`, but how would I get the remaining height after `(A)`? I would have to know the position of the `Text` widget.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303022/2233706) does not work because Flutter throws an exception when attempting to retrieve the `RenderBox` during build().

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Text('Test'), // (A) Get position of this
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DrawArea(MediaQuery.of(context).size),
          size: Size(1000, 800),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class DrawArea extends CustomPainter {
  final Size viewportSize;

  DrawArea(this.viewportSize);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    double yOffset = (this.viewportSize.width - this.viewportSize.width * .95) / 2;
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(yOffset, 0, this.viewportSize.width * .95, 800), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the `paint` method is the size of the `CustomPaint` widget.  You just need to make sure your widget gets the right size.

To make the `CustomPaint` take the rest of the space in the `Column`, you will need to wrap it in an `Expanded` widget:

```dart
      body: Column(children: [
        Text('Test'),
        Expanded(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DrawArea(),
            size: Size.infinite, // make it as large as possible
          ),
        ),
      ]),
```

Then you can just use the passed `size` parameter in your custom painter:

```dart
class DrawArea extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    double xOffset = size.width * 0.025
    double yOffset = size.height * 0.025
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(xOffset, yOffset, size.width * .95, size.height * .95), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```