# How can I determine if a rect intersects/collides with another at the bottom?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two widgets that I drag across the screen using gesturedetector.
I am aware of the method rect.contains(rect) to tell if widgets overlap, but how can I tell if a rect/widget hit the bottom of another one and if the left or right of both rects are aligned?

```
 Rect rect1 = Rect.fromLTRB(top,left,right,bottom);
    Rect rect2 =   Rect.fromLTRB(top,left,right,bottom);

     if (rect1.contains(Offset)){
     
    }
//what I want to know is:

 if (rect1.bottom.collidesWith(rect2.bottom)){
     
    }
```

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: this is a good example of what I want to achieve :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301849/how-to-check-if-two-widgets-are-overlapping-in-flutter except I want to determine collision inside the rect ( at the bottom instead of at the edges,) meaning if rect1.bottom.collidesWith(rect2.bottom). thanks