# How to get child scroll offset position in ScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I make a CustomScrollView widget that contains:

- SliverAppBar
- SliverPersistentHeader
- SliverGrid
- SliverPersistentHeader
- SliverGrid

The SliverPersistentHeader would be the description of the item in the SliverGrid, once it tapped (I wrapped it with GestureDetector) I want the scroll offset to change in the middle where the SliverPersistentHeader is.

How to do that? ScrollController seems only aware of the scroll extent, so far I do not yet see any property in ScrollView (which CustomScrollView inherit) that could give me the offset position of an individual widget.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, `ScrollController` has an offset property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/offset.html So that's the way on how to get the current offset.

If you want to scroll to a specific position, you can use the `animateTo` method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/animateTo.html. For instance:

```
scrollController.animateTo(123, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
```

In this case, you should calculate the offset value where you want to scroll (123 in the example).

In case you need to "find" that offset value, one way is to use keys on the widget and get the position of it by using the RenderObject. That's explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303022/15427566

Comment: your suggestion about finding the widget position from the RenderObject seems promising but that link you provided above seems to be outdated, I can't find the RenderObject.localToGlobal() anymore in RenderObject object.

Comment: In order to find that method, you should cast the type to RenderBox, e.g. `final renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;`.

Comment: I see I have typecast it into RenderSliver (since it was sliver) but I can't find any method equal to the method above...

Comment: @landfire13224 have you found solutions? I got an error if RenderSliver cant be used with RenderBox

Comment: Is any one found solution? I have same issue, I want to know one special child's offset in sliver

Answer (score 0):

```
final GlobalKey gKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "gkey");
void scrollToMainItemsTop() {
  // Find the context of the widget associated with the GlobalKey
  final BuildContext? context = gKey.currentContext;
  // Ensure the context is not null
  if (context != null) {
    // Ensure the widget associated with the GlobalKey is visible in the viewport
    Scrollable.ensureVisible(
      context,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }
}
```

In case of CustomScrollView this works for me
assign your sliver this gKey

Comment: Doesn't always work in a sliver list, because slivers above and below the viewport are usually not materialized, so their context is null.