# Is there a way to simulate a touch on a specific position of a widget or screen?

Tags: android, flutter, macros, click, flutter-test

I want to make a touch or tap somewhere on a widget without making the user explicitly touch the screen at that point. Is there any way to do so?

I've checked SO answers, and some recommend using "integration tests" but which is not available to do on devices which aren't physically or in some way connected to the laptop (couldn't find a better wording).

I also attempted to do a hitTest wondering if it actually touches or taps the screen at that point, while interacting with the UI, but seems like it doesn't.

```
              onPressed: () {
                    RenderObject? rb = context.findRenderObject();
                    if (rb is RenderBox){
                      final hit = BoxHitTestResult();
                      if (rb.hitTest(hit, position: Offset(300,500))){
                        print(hit.path);
                      }
                    }
                  },
```

Also, please understand the question right, as in many of the answers I've been reading regarding my query has been answered with "you don't need it, just call the function/method". I want to "simulate" a tap on a certain specified position of the screen, maybe according the X,Y axis as I attempted on the code.

An honest thank you for any directions.

If anything is lacking in my question, please let me know.

Edit: (The following is an update to what I'm finding)

I went diving into the Flutter codes. I found a few files:
Under `flutter/src/gestures/hit_test.dart` I found `void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, HitTestEntry entry);`. I assume it consumes a `PointerEvent`. Checking further,
Under `flutter/src/gestures/events.dart` I find `class PointerDownEvent extends PointerEvent` and under `flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart`
I find `class TestPointer`

Would any of these files give any light to what I want to do? I'm checking through.

Comment: `Secondly I want to ask, is there any "app development software"` asking more than one question and asking for recommendations to software in one post is a great way to get your question closed :) stick to one question at a time, don't ask for recommendations to software

Comment: you mean a workaround like this: `Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(pointer: 0, position: Offset(100, 100),));
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(pointer: 0,position: Offset(100, 100),));
});` - of course both constructors should add more properties for it to work in most cases

Comment: @a_local_nobody Right ^^ removed it!

Comment: @pskink Thank you for the comment, I'm certainly looking more infos about what you said. Is it possible for you to provide a piece code that would do something as simple as, "maybe having two ink buttons, and if the first button is pressed, simulate a tap on a position on the second button, assuming it would show ink-animation(?) too?" 
It would certainly open me up more but nevertheless I'm happy with your comment as I'm looking more about it :) thank you. Also, what do you mean by `both constructors should add more properties for it to work in most cases`?

Comment: i gave you a code how to simulate a simple `GestureDetector.onTap` event - it is done by handling pointer down event followed by pointer up event, just add some `GestureDetector` and check it, *"Also, what do you mean by both constructors should add more properties for it to work in most cases?"* - i dont know maybe `timeStamp` is required? now it is set to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/77d935af4d/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart#L1504) value

Comment: @pskink Thank you very much. I actually didn't expect `WidgetsBinding` was an instance of.. all the widgets on screen probably, dont know the better wording. Expected it to be a child under some widget and thought of some possible complications, but it has worked great as expected. I've also written this as an answer to my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink Im sorry if its not right to ping you, but I had a question related to the usage of `WidgetsBinding` that I've formed into a separate question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902255/how-can-i-simulate-a-gesture-touch-drag-on-mobile-screen . Thank you for reading ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink , the following code works the best for me/ the situation. I've been able to make the taps as wanted. Thank you very much.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(pointer: 0, position: Offset(100, 100),)); WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(pointer: 0,position: Offset(100, 100),));
```

Comment: If this workaround solved your problem, then mark it as accepted to help others know it

Comment: @Mohammad SO says I can accept my own answer in "2" days, hence cant rn. I tried before too.