# How can I simulate a gesture touch drag on mobile screen?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the following code, yes its incomplete and pretty little sphagetti as:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(pointer: 0, position: Offset(Get.width/2,Get.height/2)));
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerMoveEvent(
  pointer: 0,
  //timeStamp: Duration(seconds:10),
  position: Offset(Get.width/2+10,Get.height/2),
  // delta: Offset(-10,Get.height/2),
  // distanceMax: 0.05,
));
WidgetsBinding.instance!.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(pointer: 0),);
```

I'm trying to simulate a pointer drag on the screen, considering the screen is in landscape mode, from the middle of screen, to probably 10pixels+, to scroll the content a bit on a button-press. But the scroll is happening very fast, and sometimes scrolls with variable speed.
Could anyone recommend something?

Comment: create `AnimationController`, then call `addListener` on it and inside your listener handle a `PointerMoveEvent`s, when ready for simulation call `AnimationController.forward` (or instead you could also call `AnimationController.animateWith` but it is a more advanced usage)

Comment: @pskink I'm understanding what you mean, tho I think maybe I went off the tangents from what you suggested.. my current code is as:
https://pastie.io/xgcxze.dart

Comment: @pskink Thank you SO very much! 
Also posting it as an answer. Thank you

Comment: sure, your welcome, but actually why you have to use such workarounds if you can use directly some kind of `ScrollController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, the code he provided has been very helpful, and does answer the question too

```
late Animation<Offset> animation;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
 
  final controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  controller.addListener(_listener);
  animation = Tween(begin: Offset(100, 100), end: Offset(200, 150)).animate(controller);
 
  print('handle down event');
  controller.forward().then((value) => print('handle up event'));
}
 
_listener() {
  print('handle move event ${animation.value}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I did it

```
GestureBinding.instance
    .handlePointerEvent(const PointerDownEvent(pointer: 0));

GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(const PointerMoveEvent(
  pointer: 0,
  delta: Offset(0, 500),
));

GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(
  const PointerUpEvent(pointer: 0),
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).