# Ripple-effect programmaticaly for InkWell or InkResponse or RadioListTile

Tags: flutter, ripple-effect

What we can do to call ripple effect programmaticaly?

Example of my code:

```
return RadioListTile(
          key: _radioKey,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          value: radioValue,
          groupValue: radioGroupValue,
          activeColor: AppColors.underlineColor,
          toggleable: true,
          enableFeedback: true,
          onChanged: (int? value) {
            _onSelectItem();
          },
          dense: false,
          title: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
            child: Text(
              widget.title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.color,
                fontSize: 16
              ),
          )),
          Text(
            widget.subtitle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.color,
              fontSize: 14
            ),
          )
```

the problem is when i click on the circle of RadioListTile there is no ripple-effect, can i do it programmaticaly?

Comment: Are you looking to add effect for the circle or the radio tile?

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373396/trigger-inkwell-without-tapping-on-it

Comment: @lepsch thx, i try to use RenderBox with hitTest, but it not working for radio tile

Comment: @KaushikChandru, looking to add effect for radio tile, cause then i tap on circle (of this radio tile) there no effect. So i want to add this effect programmaticaly and want to know how to add ripple effects without tapping.

Comment: Wrap the radio tile with ink widget and try once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) to make the radio invisible to hit testing. So, only the [`InkResponse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html) behind it is going to receive the taps. BTW, only `InkResponse` or only `InkWell` is enough. `InkWell` is a specialized `InkResponse` that doesn't clip splashes and is always rectangular.

Check out the result below and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=78eda3c34052ac0684674b7fbb130052):

[image: Screenshot]

The code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool radioValue = false;
  bool? radioGroupValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkResponse(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              radioGroupValue =
                  radioGroupValue == null ? true : !radioGroupValue!;
            });
          },
          highlightShape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
          highlightColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
          hoverColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
          containedInkWell: true,
          child: IgnorePointer(
            child: RadioListTile(
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.platform,
              value: true,
              groupValue: radioGroupValue,
              // activeColor: AppColors.underlineColor,
              toggleable: true,
              enableFeedback: true,
              onChanged: (_) {},
              dense: false,
              title: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    widget.title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.color,
                        fontSize: 16),
                  )),
              subtitle: Text(
                'subtitleLang',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.color,
                    fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```